# How can I change the x axis so there is no white space?

Tags: python, matplotlib

So currently learning how to import data and work with it in matplotlib and I am having trouble even tho I have the exact code from the book.

[image]

This is what the plot looks like, but my question is how can I get it where there is no white space between the start and the end of the x-axis.

Here is the code:

```
import csv

from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from datetime import datetime

# Get dates and high temperatures from file.
filename = 'sitka_weather_07-2014.csv'
with open(filename) as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    header_row = next(reader)

    #for index, column_header in enumerate(header_row):
        #print(index, column_header)
    dates, highs = [], []
    for row in reader:
        current_date = datetime.strptime(row[0], "%Y-%m-%d")
        dates.append(current_date)

        high = int(row[1])
        highs.append(high)

# Plot data. 
fig = plt.figure(dpi=128, figsize=(10,6))
plt.plot(dates, highs, c='red')


# Format plot.
plt.title("Daily high temperatures, July 2014", fontsize=24)
plt.xlabel('', fontsize=16)
fig.autofmt_xdate()
plt.ylabel("Temperature (F)", fontsize=16)
plt.tick_params(axis='both', which='major', labelsize=16)

plt.show()
```

Answer (score 133, accepted):

There is an automatic margin set at the edges, which ensures the data to be nicely fitting within the axis spines. In this case such a margin is probably desired on the y axis. By default it is set to `0.05` in units of axis span.

To set the margin to `0` on the x axis, use

```
plt.margins(x=0)
```

or

```
ax.margins(x=0)
```

depending on the context. Also see [the documentation](http://matplotlib.org/devdocs/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.margins.html).

In case you want to get rid of the margin in the whole script, you can use

```
plt.rcParams['axes.xmargin'] = 0
```

at the beginning of your script (same for `y` of course). If you want to get rid of the margin entirely and forever, you might want to change the according line in the [matplotlib rc file](http://matplotlib.org/users/customizing.html):

```
axes.xmargin : 0
axes.ymargin : 0
```

### Example

```py
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

tips = sns.load_dataset('tips')

fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(1, 2, figsize=(10, 4))
tips.plot(ax=ax1, title='Default Margin')
tips.plot(ax=ax2, title='Margins: x=0')
ax2.margins(x=0)
```

[image]

---

Alternatively, use [`plt.xlim(..)`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.xlim.html) or [`ax.set_xlim(..)`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_xlim.html) to manually set the limits of the axes such that there is no white space left.

Answer (score 2):

If you only want to remove the margin on one side but not the other, e.g. remove the margin from the right but not from the left, you can use `set_xlim()` on a matplotlib axes object.

```
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import math

max_x_value = 100

x_values = [i for i in range (1, max_x_value + 1)]
y_values = [math.log(i) for i in x_values] 

fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(1, 2, figsize=(10, 4))
sn.lineplot(ax=ax1, x=x_values, y=y_values)
sn.lineplot(ax=ax2, x=x_values, y=y_values)
ax2.set_xlim(-5, max_x_value) # tune the -5 to your needs
```

[image]