# Seaborn - remove spacing from DataFrame histogram

Tags: python, pandas, seaborn

I am trying to generate a histogram from a DataFrame with `seaborn` enabled via the [`DataFrame.hist`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.hist.html) method, but I keep finding extra space added to either side of the histogram itself, as seen by the red arrows in the below picture:
[image: Histogram with additional spacing]

How can I remove these spaces? Code to reproduce this graph is as follows:

```
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

from random import seed, choice
seed(0)

df = pd.DataFrame([choice(range(250)) for _ in range(100)], columns=['Values'])

bins = np.arange(0, 260, 10)

df['Values'].hist(bins=bins)
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

Comment: There are no spaces in the begining and end when I try the code in my machine.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`plt.tight_layout()` only has an effect for the "outer margins" of your plot (tick marks, ax labels etc.).

By default matplotlib's hist leaves an inner margin around the hist bar-plot. To disable you can do this:

```
ax = df['Values'].hist(bins=bins)
ax.margins(x=0)
plt.show()
```

Comment: This does indeed remove the spaces! Thankyou. I'll leave the question for a little longer to see if there are any further explanations as to why this happens, and mark yours as the answer if none appears.

Comment: Using `xlim` requires to know or determine the desired limits. A better solution is surely to use `ax.margins(x=0)` as in  [the duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42045767/how-can-i-change-the-x-axis-in-matplotlib-so-there-is-no-white-space).

Comment: indeed, updated to include this cleaner solution

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest you're right - apologies for missing the dupe, too.