# set xlim with datetime values

Tags: pandas, matplotlib, python-3.6

I am trying to modify the graph [image: graph] specifically I do not like seeing the spaces to the left and to the right on the x axis and would like it to squeeze to fit.

the values of the x axis are datetime objects.

```
xmin,xmax = plt.xlim()
print(xmax)
print(xmin)
```

returns

```
17707.15
16757.85
```

What is the proper way to modify these limits? Should I convert the correct datetime object to an int and set xlim using that. Or is there a function within matplotlib that will remove these gaps (only on the x axis) for me.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I change the x axis in matplotlib so there is no white space?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42045767/how-can-i-change-the-x-axis-in-matplotlib-so-there-is-no-white-space)

Comment: It is the same problem with a different solution. Also the question is worded differently. and identifies a specific conceptual issue regarding xlim()'s interpretation of datetime

Answer (score 1):

```
ax.autoscale(enable=True, axis='x', tight=True)
```

produced

[image]
Sourced from https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.autoscale.html