# Matplotlib - Histogram - First bin doesn't start at the beginning of X-axis

Tags: python, matplotlib, histogram, x-axis

In this post i'm not talking about how bins are calculated.

I want that the first bin gets located at the beginning of the X-axis.

In other words :

I want that the first bin gets located where is the Y-axis

Here is my source code :

```
import random
import pandas as pd
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

# Preparing the variable
data = {}
data["values"] = [random.randint(0,50) for x in range(200)]
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# Creation of the figure
plt.figure(figsize = (10, 10))
plt.subplot(1, 1, 1)

# Creation of my bins
mybins = [-0.5+x for x in range(0,52)]

# Creation of the chart
plt.hist(df["values"], bins=mybins,
         rwidth=0.7, align="mid")

plt.xticks(list(range(0, 51, 5)))

plt.show()
```

As an output i get this histogram :

[image: histogram_first_bin_shifted]

As you can see, there is blank space between the Y-axis and the first bin.

Comment: You have 51 values but only 50 bins.

Comment: Better use `bins=np.arange(df["values"].min()-.5, df["values"].max()+1)` to have nice bins around the discrete values.

Comment: You can also try seaborn's `sns.histplot(...., discrete=True)` to get nice histogram bins. Or `sns.countplot()` as a discrete histogram is basically counting each x-value once.

Comment: I don't talk about how bins are calculated. There is a "free space" between the Y Axis and the start of the first bin. This is what i want to avoid. Please review your judgement and reopen my question.

Comment: Try [`plt.margins(x=0.01)`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.margins.html).

Comment: @Mr.T: You provided the right answer. It would really worth reopening this question.

Comment: In this case, the question is a duplicate of this: https://stackoverflow.com/q/42045767/8881141