# Remove white space plot matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I'm trying to get something like this:

[image]

with this code

```py
x = np.arange(l, r, s)
y = np.arange(b, t, s)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)
Z = f(X,Y)

plt.axis('equal')
plt.pcolormesh(X, Y, Z)
plt.savefig("image.png",dpi=300)
```

But I get this:

[image]

How could I remove the white regions?
I really appreciate any kind of help.

Comment: Remove `plt.axis('equal')`

Comment: I want the axis to be equal

Comment: [`plt.axis('equal')`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.axis.html) is a shortcut for `ax.set_aspect('equal', adjustable='datalim')`.   You might want to change it to `plt.axis('scaled')` which adjusts the box instead of the datalim.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i would use the pyplot subplots to define the figures size and therefor aspect like this

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

def f(x,y):
    return x + y

x = np.arange(1, 10, .1)
y = np.arange(1, 10, .1)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)
Z = f(X,Y)


f, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(4, 4))
plt.pcolormesh(X, Y, Z)
plt.show()
```

output

[image]

as pointed out by @JohanC, this also works and might be a better solution in some cases. it does not require the 'subplots' function which returns a figure and a subplot.

```
plt.pcolormesh(X, Y, Z)
plt.axis('scaled')
plt.show()
```

output

[image]

Answer (score -1):

[Anwered here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42045767/how-can-i-change-the-x-axis-in-matplotlib-so-there-is-no-white-space/42045987#42045987) You can remove the margins at the edges of the plot.

```py
plt.margins(x=0)
```

Comment: It doesn't work